# Laravel sanctum works in localhost, but returns 401 unauthenticated in live server

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

This is my 3rd post in a row on this issue, unfortunately I am not getting proper answer. I am developing an authentication system using laravel-sanctum in a laravel-vuejs app. The laravel-sanctum works fine (return user info from "/api/user" api) in the localhost. But when I am deploying in a live server, it returns 401 (unauthenicated) error.

my .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:WvNeYkRnJbXNcttmiAKe1blplUslHWIsRQpvnPt0mxA=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://subdomain.domain.com/


DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=subdomain.domain.com
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
SANCTUM_STATIC_DOMAIN=subdomain.domain.com
```

My sanctum.php

`'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'subdomain.domain.com')),`

`'guard' => ['api'],`

cors.php

`'supports_credentials' => true,`

auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

From bootstrap.js

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 
'XMLHttpRequest';

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

Code from component (script)

```
mounted() {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${this.token}`;
    axios.get('/api/user').then(response => {
        this.userInfo = response.data
    })
}
```

Comment: Do you use Laravel `auth middleware` ?

Comment: yes I am using auth middleware

Comment: I am not sure whether I properly configured auth middleware or not though

Comment: I'm not fully understand your app but can you try with my answer below if it might helps.

Comment: I never used the first line of your mounted method before, and never faced the same issue you have. It might be the problem. Second, I think your stateful domain should contain https:// part too.

Comment: @Bulent It's used for token authentication each time request sends

Comment: @Bulent I have corrected the stateful domain :)

Comment: Did it help or still the same?

Comment: You don't need attach the token each time. It's handled by withCredentials settings.

Comment: oh, alright I am trying again

Comment: Do you really need the sanctum token configuration? Because cookie config is much simpler to do an have less problems. I recommend you to use it if your app is not going to be used with native apps, just from browser.

Comment: @Guille that does not work either brother, I have some core issue in my sanctum/middleware config I guess

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define home url in the blade page you use vue app like this.

```
<script>
      window.home = "<?php echo your-host-url ?>";
</script>
```

To make sure the API route is correct you add:

```
axios.get(window.home + '/api/user').then(response => {
    this.userInfo = response.data
})
```

Comment: does not work brother

Answer (score -1):

The solution is adding this to .htaccess of root folder (not only inside the public folder)

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```